# How to solve "PHP Fatal error: Declaration must be comatible with PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase::getStatus()"?

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-8

I use PHPUnit 9.0., Laravel framework 8.* and PHP 7.4.

I run into an PHP Fatal error by using a Trait that has a same method name like a class at the PhpUnit Framework.

The Error is:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of App\Traits\ExampleTrait::getStatus(App\Example\ExampleConnectionInterface $example_connection, $unique_id) 
must be compatible with PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase::getStatus(): int in /home/vagrant/code/tests/Integration/JobTests/ExampleJobTest.php 
on line 204
```

The `ExampleJobTest.php` looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Integration\JobTests\Examples;

use App\Traits\ExampleTrait;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Tests\TestCase;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    use WithoutMiddleware;
    use DatabaseTransactions;
    use ExampleTrait;

    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->example_connection = new ExampleConnection();
    }

}
```

I have to use the `App\Traits\ExampleTrait` many times for different Tests and everytime I run in this error. When I rename the function `App\Traits\ExampleTrait::getStatus(...)` into another name the error doesn't occur.

Of Course, the easiest and fastest way would be to rename the function in `App\Traits\ExampleTrait`, but my team asked me to find another solution.

So, is there way to fix this error **without** renaming the function name in `App\Traits\ExampleTrait`?

Comment: You can use the insteadof and alias keywords to resolve the conflict. For more information, see the php documents https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php

Comment: No it doesn't work, because ```PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase``` is not a Trait and like the documentation says insteadof and alias can be used for Traits. But in my case I have a Trait and an abstract Class

Comment: ah sorry, I had misread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPUnit's `TestCase` class already uses a method named `getStatus`. You cannot override it if the signatures don't match, and you **should not** override it, unless you really need this to be overriden. PHPUnit uses this method internally

---

Solution: Choose a different name for that method and you're done.

Comment: Can you enlighten on this?.

Comment: What's your question about this?

Comment: You have to provide a working solution with examples as like above answers.

Comment: "Choose a different name for that method and you're done" - is there anything unclear about this hint?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply rename the `ExampleTrait::getStatus` in `ExampleTest`

```php
use ExampleTrait {
    ExampleTrait::getStatus as exampleTraitGetStatus;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should **NEVER** `use` (a trait) from `App` inside a test class... So you are already doing something wrong...

Second of all, the error is pretty explanatory, you are overriding `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase::getStatus` because your trait implements the same method, so you have some solutions:

1. Stop using the trait inside your test/move it into the `tests` folder and rename the method.
2. Use an alias for the method:

```
use ExampleTrait {
    ExampleTrait::getStatus as exampleGetStatus;
}
```

3. I have no idea what is `getStatus` doing (also rename your trait please, what the hell is `ExampleTrait`?), but you can update `getStatus` to have the same signing as the `TestCase` method. Your trait's method should be `getStatus(): int` without any parameters, but I doubt this would fix your issue as I have no idea what you are using this method for...

So, the best solution for you would be `1.`.